# Calling and passing objects to a custom method in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have, what I have to imagine is a very simple question about calling custom controller methods and passing data to them.

I've added a custom method `dprocess` to the controller for the purposes of acting on `post objects` that I have listed in my `index`, to be called with some sort of button.  The method `dprocess` does not have any view but simply processes the data in `post` and saves the result to a file in `/tmp/`.  The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to pass the data to this custom method.

**So Here's my index.html.erb**

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="Name"><%= link_to post.name, post %></td>
      <td class="created_at"><%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(post) %></td>
      <td class="generate"><%= button_to "Process Post", ........ %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Note the "........" in `button_to`; the missing contents are what I'm struggling to figure out.

**My question is:** How can I pass `post` to this custom method in the controller?

Many thanks for ANY guidance; this problem has been killing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the special attribute `remote` on `link_to`, `button_to` methods to indicate that you want to perform an AJAX operation.

Assuming your routes look like:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    # note: the post here means a HTTP POST request is necessary, if you want 
    # a HTTP GET request, change it to get
    post 'dprocess'
  end
end
```

So the url will look like `/posts/:id/dprocess`

Then you can perform an AJAX request when clicking the button like this, please 
make sure you change the `method` attribute to either `:post` or `:get` depending on how you have configured your route.

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="Name"><%= link_to post.name, post %></td>
      <td class="created_at"><%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(post) %></td>
      <td class="generate"><%= button_to "Process Post", dprocess_post_path(post), :remote => true, :method => :post %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

This will call your controller action `dprocess` using a POST request:

```
def dprocess 
  # find object
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  # ... perform processing

  # render nothing
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Having a look at the documentation is usually a good guidance:

[button_to documentation, see "Options" sections](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

[Rails Guide on AJAX helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: As an update, I had to get rid of the `render :nothing => true` line.  I don't know if it had anything to do with the script I was running (I don't see anything to indicate that it would) but in cased anyone else runs into a `DoubleRenderError`, get rid of the last line.

Comment: this happens when you have a template defined for the `dprocess` action.